# How to Prevent Component from unmounting in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two components, say a loader and a calendar. Till Calendar fetches data, the `loader` component should appear and whenever data is fetched, the calendar `component` should render. I am using Redux to manage my app's state. Calendar has its own state and upon some changes, I want to maintain it, so I need calendar not to unmount rather stay in the DOM. So, whenever my current component's view changes, loader should come and calendar should hide instead unmounting. How can I do this?

Currently I have written :

```
render() {
    let that = this,
      { loading } = that.props;

    return loading ? that.renderLoader() : that.renderCalendar();
  }
```

Calendar has its onChange upon I am fetching data from API hooks using Redux:

```
onChange = (params) => {
        //API Hooks
}
```

How can I prevent unmounting of calendar if the component re-renders. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using redux, why don't you store the State of the calendar in redux?  That way It doesn't matter if it unmounts or remounts.

Comment: Be exprerience, your need answer to a problem that should be resolved in another way. Use redux to condition your component state.

Answer (score 1):

If hiding is what you want to do, then why not literally hide it using css?

```
render() {
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{display: loading ? 'inline' : 'none'}}>
        {that.renderLoader()
      </div>
      {!loading ? that.renderCalendar() : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In other words, _decide whether to make the element VISIBLE, not whether to RENDER IT_. This is the way to go. I recommend applying a CSS class (instead of using inline styles as in this short example), take a look at the `classnames` module

Answer (score 0):

```
return loading ? that.renderLoader() : that.renderCalendar();
```

This way; you cant prevent the component to be unmounted. The  only way should be to have the component always displayed at the top of other components and then hidden or show with jQuery functions. Linking this calendatr to a redux `reducer` will have the calendar state changed to your need when displayed.